# CentOS name resolving issues

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, centos, vmware-server

I have the following setup.

A Centos machine (let say name is centoshost) connected to network and has static ip also running DNS server (BIND). IP is 192.168.1.33

Another CentOS virtual machine (centosguest) on centoshost (VMWare Server 2) IP of centosguest is 192.168.1.34 . Network adapter is bridged.

A windows machine connected to network and gets IP with DHCP from my router

All 3 machines have access to internet.

All 3 machines can ping others IP addresses

Here is the problem

On windows machine, I can ping "centoshost" name but I can't ping centosguest

On centoshost I can't ping centosguest

On centosguest I can't ping centoshost

I don't want to play with hosts file because I want who ever connect to network must see the centoshost and centosguest with their names.

I have DNS server on centoshost but not sure if it's needed to solve this issue.

What should I do to make both centoshost and centosguest accessible with their names not only with their IPs?

Thanks in advance
Ergec

Comment: Ok I configured DNS on host machine so I can access guest machine from network using "guest.local" name . Creating an empty zone name is not allowed. So I created a zone named "local" and put guest under it. I can accept this solution but still didn't understand why just "guest" name doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your router is running DHCP?  Make sure its got your DNS server in there and is handing out that IP as the DNS server properly.

If you confirm that it is, then you'll want to check your DNS zones, and see if they're being updated.  If they are, flush DNS caches, and take interfaces down and back up.

If you're still having issues, I would say it's a host/guest communication issue.. perhaps they're on different subnets with a local DHCP server running on the host.

But it's hard to be sure.  My experience of VMWare, anyway, shows that "Bridged," mode may not be what I originally expected.